# How to design a fan that can be used to convert concentrated air to power

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pressure, turbines

I am trying to design mechanism that is sort of like a wind turbine (uses wind as "fuel") but has a fan size that is in a pelton turbine. I was wondering if there is any math/equation that I can use to know how much power can be generated or how many rpms can the fan produce when attached to a generator. The equation of the wind turbine is not that applicable because the wind coming in will be going through a pipe (like in a peloton turbine, which has water), and the fan size is too small.

Is there an equation relating air velocity in a pipe and how much power that can generate?

Comment: Complication factors will be the number of blades in the fan (2, 3, 4 ...), the angle of the blades and the shape of the blades (narrow quasi-elliptical to wide area lobes).  If the book is still in print, or there's a copy in a technical library somewhere, look at B. B Daly, *Woods Practical Guide to Fan Engineering*, published by Woods of Colchester Limited (a GEC company).